# IndexError : list index out of range Please let me know why isnt my code working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The following question is to print all the words which start with an `s` using `.split()`,for and if  in the given below statement `(st)` the code I have written isn't working for some reason it says `indexerror`.

Here's my code

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'

x=st.split()

i=0

j=0

for y in x:

        i+=1
        if x[i][j]=='s':
            print(y)
```

The error that I've received

```
that

with

this
```

> Traceback (most recent call last)
>       IndexError: list index out of range

Why are the words `that`, `with`, `this` are being displayed can  anyone explain?

The ideal code apparently posted by my prof is

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'

for word in st.split():

     if word[0] == 's':

      print(word)
```

I don't really understand the difference between his code and mine, what I actually mean is that i just referenced the `.split()` to the variable `x` in my code and used 2 other variables `i,j` for checking the 1st letter of the `list x`, please help me understand whats wrong.

Comment: Try going through this with pen and paper, writing down the value of each variable at every step…

Comment: `print('\n'.join(word for word in st.split() if word.startswith('s')))`. It has `split()`, `for` and `if`.

Comment: move `i+=1` to the end of for loop , ideally try debugging your code by printing out values on each step, check the values of `x,y,i,x[i][j]` at each step, you will understand more.

Answer (score 2):

## Your Code :

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
x=st.split() 
# x = ['Print', 'only', 'the', ...] you are actually spliting the sentence into 
#       indvidual words 

i=0
j=0

# now when you loop this list 
for y in x:
    # y = 'Print' , second time y = 'only'
    i+=1
    # x[1][0] i.e i = 1 , j= 0 , you miss the first value and at last pass i=11 , but the maximim allowed index is 10 as len(x) = 11, as index starts from 0 so 11-1 is the maximum allowed index   
    if x[i][j]=='s':
        print(y)
```

## Correct in your code

move i+=1 after the if statement, at the end of the loop and

```
for y in x:    
 if x[i][j]=='s':
    print(y)
 i+=1
```

## Correct way:

i and j are serving no purpose as y contains the individual words, hence instead of x[i][j] use y[0] i.e for the first time when y = 'Print', y[0] = P and so on

```
for y in x:    
 if y[0]=='s':
    print(y)
```

## Your Professor's code:

As you can see how your code looks similar to that of your professor. The only thing is that, as he is experienced he knows that a split return a list of elements and we loop on a list hence he merges two statements i.e x = st.split()  and for y in x  into one.

```
for word in st.split(): # for words in ["Print", "only", "the", "words" ...]

 if word[0] == 's':

  print(word)
```

Comment: @sourabh any reason answer accepted and then not accepted?